# Windows 11 Outlook Behaviour "Mark messages as read when deleted" not working (gmail)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I [have had this problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utFHMh20JYs) for a while now (I checked the "Mark messages as read when deleted" checkbox but it doesn't work).

My outlook version:

```
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20182) 64-bit
```

**It seems that the problem is only linked to gmail**, because on another mailbox (one related to where I work), the option works.

Useless context: even if it's minor (at first I just recorded it for the bants), it is quite annoying as I receive a lot of emails from slurm and I don't like having unread messages in my bin (*Corbeille* is the French word for *bin*).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a video explaining exactly the problem. I checked the "Mark messages as read when deleted" checkbox and it doesn't work. I don't know how I can make the post more understandable @Community Bot

Comment: You could define the problem in text. YouTube is not part of our site.

Comment: When I delete emails, I empty the folder. I don’t use Deleted items as a storage folder.

Comment: @harrymc I've added the problem in text, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @John this is very cumbersome to do ...

Comment: I don't think so. Right Click on Deleted Items and select Delete. Quite simple and easy to do.

Comment: In fact, in that menu, you can also Mark all as Read.  Again, since right context, it is all really easy to do.

Comment: I know that's what I currently do, but I'm looking for a way to not have to doing it :/

Answer (score 1):

***Updated:***

As shown in the below figure, when the unread messages in the **inbox** are moved to the **Trash** folder, they will be marked as read.

[image]

Is your mailbox shown as mine?

---

Do you mean it didn't work when you select the below option?

[image]

If so, does this issue occur recently? Have you done any specific operations before that? Such as installing some third-party add-ins?

Based on my test on this option, the unread emails are marked as read after i delete them. What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

On the other hand, it's suggested that you could uncheck it > restart Outlook > check it again to check if there're any differences.

If the issue still exists, considering that it would also be affected when the outlook program itself is damaged, it is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: `uncheck it > restart Outlook > check it again` didn't work

Comment: I've added my outlook version to the post, good idea

Comment: This occured as soon as I checked it, I'd never checked it before and tried to check it and it appears it doesn't work on my end.

Comment: It seems that the problem is only linked to gmail, because on another mailbox (one related to where I work), the option works. I've edited accordingly my question.

Comment: How did you configure your Gmail account? Based on my test on Gmail(configured as IMAP), the option works.

Comment: I configured it as IMAP/SMTP. I'm not too knowledgeable on what those things are though.

Comment: Hi @FluidMechanics Potential Flows! I have updated my reply above, please feel free to check it.

Comment: I have a trash folder (except the name is French 'Corbeille'), but inside that folder I also have subfloders. Maybe something went wrong with all of that? Cf. https://i.imgur.com/IhZnFhF.png Weirdly enough I have several trash folders ('Corbeille' folders)

Comment: So which Trash folder were deleted items moved into? On the other hand, it's suggested that you could log into Gmail web mail and delete the lablels that are not needed.

Comment: I deleted the labels that are not needed. It does appear more clean, however it did not fix the problem. I tried unticking, restarting outlook and ticking back just in case, but still doesn't work either.